# Resizing an image using PIL in pre_save signal

Tags: python, django

Here's my code:

```
from PIL import Image
from pilkit.processors import ResizeToFit

def before_saving_shop(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    img = Image.open(instance.logo)
    processor = ResizeToFit(100, 100)
    instance.logo = processor.process(img)

pre_save.connect(before_saving_shop, sender=Shop)
```

I am getting this exception:

```
Exception Value: _committed
```

Please help.

Comment: You must post the full stack trace. Just the exception value is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You no need use signal for this purpose. Just redefine save method of the Shop model like this:

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    ....

    def save(self):
        img = Image.open(self.logo)
        processor = ResizeToFit(100, 100)
        self.logo = processor.process(img)
        super(Shop, self).save()
```